# Differential equation of first order — omitting absolute value. Why is it omitted and when should I omit it?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following simple exercise:
$$ \text{Solve: } y' = 2(x - xy) $$

The equation is the same as:

$$\frac{dy}{1-y} = 2x \ dx$$

Integrating both sides, we have:

$$-\text{ln}(|1-y|) + C_1 = x^2 + C_2 $$

So:

$$ |1-y| = e^{-x^2-C} $$

The expected result is:

$$y = e^{-x^2-C} + 1$$

**Why is the absolute value omitted? It seems $|1-y|$ becomes $y-1$.**

Thank you!

**NOTE:** I read a few posts here, about this, but I can't understand on this case, why the absolute value is omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integration is correct, $|1-y|=e^{-x^2-C} $ is indeed the (implicit) solution. However, note that due to the $|\cdot|$, we actually end up having two families of curves.

Note first that $e^{-x^2-C}= e^{-C}e^{-x^2}=Ke^{-x^2}$, where $K=e^{-C}$ is an arbitrary constant.

Another piece of information is that:

$$Ke^{-x^2}=|\pm(Ke^{-x^2})|$$

Use this to conclude that $|1-y|=|\pm(Ke^{-x^2})|$, so the solutions in $y$ are:

$$1-y=Ke^{-x^2} \implies y=-Ke^{-x^2}+1$$
$$1-y=-Ke^{-x^2} \implies y=Ke^{-x^2}+1$$

Since $K$ is an arbitrary constant, the $-$ sign can be absorbed. We can in fact say that $M=\pm K$ with $y=Me^{-x^2}+1$. We can then drop the absolute value sign after collecting constants.

Note: If an initial condition is specified, we would then have to worry about the constants and whether it is $+$ or $-$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand.